# XQuery in collection within some XML files

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, exist-db

I am using eXist-db for XML file handling. I have a collection named `/db/Sample/Mycollection`.  To iterate over all files in the collection I can use

```
for $x in collection("/db/Sample/Mycollection")
let $z:= ...
return ...
```

But in this collection I have files with filenames 2060.xml, 2061.xml, and so on. Now I want to query over first 10 files like 2060.xml to 2069.xml or any number of files. How can I achieve this? Is there any function that can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subsequence()` function is your friend. To query over only the first 10 files:

```
for $x in subsequence(collection("/db/Sample/Mycollection), 1, 10)
```